# Date is not getting updated in partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have normal view and partial view .Date is not getting updated which is in Normal view to the Partial View.I have Tried,

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    onSelect: function () {
        selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("DD/MM/YYYY", $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
        alert(selectedDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution of how to use JQuery Date Time Picker with ASP.NET MVC.

[Simplest Way to Use JQuery Date Picker and Date Time Picker in ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1136464/Simplest-Way-to-Use-JQuery-Date-Picker-and-Date-Ti)

Comment: Its all Ok,but when i want to update a date then its taking a initial date i have tried, $("#datetimepicker1").change(function () {
            selectedDate = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
            alert(selectedDate);
            $(".pqr").val(selectedDate);
            
           
        });
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker('hide');
        });   Its working but showing another calender